# Realloc not working in my program, any ideas why?

Tags: c, structure, realloc

I am trying to write a program that is going to use the Huffman algorithm to create a dictionary to compress a text file. I am having some problems regarding `realloc`. My program works just fine, but valgrind reports a lot of errors regarding `realloc`. I tried writing my own and using the function but nothing works. Any ideas?

If you want to check the output you have to do it like "-o 1 -f read.txt -v"

read.txt could be a any text file that has words that are in ASCII table

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

const int expand_size = 4;
int length = 4;

typedef struct {
    char w[2]; //word
    int v; //value
    int d; //direction
    char b; //binary
} node_t;

int maxi(node_t * huff, int n) {
    int maxi = huff[0].v;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (huff[i].v > maxi) {
            maxi = huff[i].v;
        }
    return maxi;
}

int mini(node_t * huff, int n) {
    int mini = maxi(huff, n);
    int w = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (huff[i].v <= mini && huff[i].v >= 0) {
            w = i;
            mini = huff[i].v;
        }
    return w;
}

node_t * realoc(node_t * huff) {
    node_t * temp = realloc(huff, (length + expand_size) * sizeof(node_t));
    return temp;
}

int huffman(node_t * huff, int n) {
    int j = 1;
    int i = 1;

    int index1;
    int index2;
    int value1;
    int value2;

    while (i != n) {
        index1 = mini(huff, n);
        value1 = huff[index1].v;
        huff[index1].v = -1;
        index2 = mini(huff, n);
        value2 = huff[index2].v;
        huff[index2].v = -1;

        huff[index1].d = n;
        huff[index2].d = n;

        huff[index1].b = '1';
        huff[index2].b = '0';

        if (n == length) {
            node_t * temp;
            temp = realoc(huff);
            huff = temp;
            for (int h = length; h < length + expand_size; h++) {
                huff[h].v = 0;
            }
            length += expand_size;
        }

        huff[n].v = value1 + value2;
        huff[n].w[0] = j + '0';
        j++;
        i = i + 2;
        n++;

    }
    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int n;
    ///reading from a file///
    FILE * read;
    char word[2];
    char c;

    ///getopt parimeters///
    int opt;
    char * file = NULL;
    char steps = 0;
    char compression_level = 0;

    ///getopt///
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "o:f:v")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {

        case 'f':
            file = optarg;
            break;

        case 'v':
            steps = 1;
            break;

        case 'o':
            compression_level = atof(optarg);
            break;

        case '?':
            printf("Złe parametry wywołania");
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    read = fopen(file, "r");

    node_t * huff = malloc(sizeof(node_t) * (length));

    int counter = 0; ///how many nodes are in the table (nodes from the file not the ones that we create with huffman algorithm)

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        huff[i].v = 0;

    if (read == NULL) {
        printf("file can't be opened \n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (compression_level == 1) {
        while ((c = fgetc(read)) != EOF) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (huff[i].v == 0) {
                    huff[i].w[0] = c;
                    huff[i].v++;
                    counter++;
                    break;
                }
                if (huff[i].w[0] == c) {
                    huff[i].v++;
                    break;
                }
                if (i == length - 1) {
                    node_t * temp;
                    temp = realoc(huff);
                    huff = temp;
                    for (int j = length; j < length + expand_size; j++) {
                        huff[j].v = 0;
                        //huff[j].w[0] = ' ';
                    }
                    length += expand_size;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    n = huffman(huff, counter);

    ///printing the table///

    int l;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        l = i;

        if (compression_level == 1)
            printf("%c: ", huff[i].w[0]);

        if (compression_level == 2)
            printf("%c%c: ", huff[i].w[0], huff[i].w[1]);

        while (l != n - 1) {
            printf("%c", huff[l].b);
            l = huff[l].d;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    if (steps == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            if (huff[i].w[0] == 10)
                printf("'%d' 'LINE FEED' occured %d razy\n", huff[i].w[0], huff[i].v);
            //else printf("'%d' '%s' wystapilo %d razy\n", huff[i].w, huff[i].w, huff[i].v);
        }
        printf("array length %d\n", length);
        printf("how many nodes %d\n", n);
        printf("how many primary nodes %d\n", counter);
        //printf("v = %d, o = %d\n", steps, compression_level);
    }
    free(huff);
    fclose(read);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check the return of `realloc()` otherwise you leak memory on failure (that's the whole point of assigning the return value to a temp).  Avoid global variables whenever possible.

Comment: What are the errors that you're getting from valgrind?

Comment: fgetc() returns an int not a char i..e `int c`.

Comment: We could need a copy of read.txt to reproduce it, too.

Comment: If -f option is not specified you end up doing fopen(NULL) which will segfault.  Use positional arguments if it's required instead of options, which are supposed to be optional.

Comment: Valgrind reports several errors about accesses to memory after it is freed.  This is not an issue inside `realloc`.  It is about your code's (mis)use of pointers.

Comment: Invalid read of size 1, size 4.  Looks like the the print statements in the loop ` for(int i=0; i<counter; i++){ ` This is my favorite "More than 10000000 total errors detected" :-)

Comment: oh, so the problem isn't with me messing up realloc but with me messing up something else? Great XD

Comment: `int huffman(node_t *huff, int n)` cannot be correct, if you realloc, then you need to pass in a **huff.  Yeah that was it.

Comment: So i just have to give pointer to it in function? Like "int huffman(node_t **huff, int n)"

Comment: @MichałJagodzinski Yup, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `int huffman(node_t *huff, int n)` you try to `realloc()` the `huff` pointer but in C we pass variables by value so you only receive a copy of the pointer.  This means caller retains the original pointer and the `realloc()` memory is lost when you return from the function.  You need to pass in a `**huff`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

const int expand_size = 4;
int length = 4;

typedef struct {
    char w[2]; //word
    int v; //value
    int d; //direction
    char b; //binary
} node_t;

int maxi(node_t *huff, int n) {
    int maxi = huff[0].v;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(huff[i].v>maxi)
            maxi=huff[i].v;
    return maxi;
}

int mini(node_t *huff, int n) {
    int mini = maxi(huff, n);
    int w=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(huff[i].v<=mini && huff[i].v >=0){
            w=i;
            mini=huff[i].v;
        }
    return w;
}

int huffman(node_t **huff, int n){
    int j=1;
    int i=1;
    while (i!=n){
        int index1=mini(*huff, n);
        int value1=(*huff)[index1].v;
        (*huff)[index1].v=-1;
        int index2=mini(*huff, n);
        int value2=(*huff)[index2].v;
        (*huff)[index2].v=-1;
        (*huff)[index1].d = n;
        (*huff)[index2].d = n;
        (*huff)[index1].b = '1';
        (*huff)[index2].b = '0';
        if ( n == length ){
            node_t *temp = realloc(*huff, (length + expand_size) * sizeof *temp);
            if(!temp) {
                printf("realloc failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            *huff=temp;
            for ( int h = length; h < length + expand_size; h++){
                (*huff)[h].v = 0;
            }
            length += expand_size;
        }
        (*huff)[n].v=value1 + value2;
        (*huff)[n].w[0]=j+'0';
        j++;
        i=i+2;
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv) {
    int opt;
    char *file = NULL;
    char steps = 0;
    char compression_level = 0;
    while ((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "o:f:v")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'f':
                file = optarg;
                break;

            case 'v':
                steps = 1;
                break;

            case 'o':
                compression_level = atof ( optarg );
                break;

            case '?':
                printf("Złe parametry wywołania");
                return 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    if(!file) {
        printf("file is required\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    FILE *read = fopen(file, "r");
    node_t *huff = malloc(length * sizeof *huff);
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        huff[i].v = 0;

    if (read == NULL) {
        printf ("file can't be opened \n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(compression_level == 1){
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(read)) != EOF ){
            for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
                if (!huff[i].v){
                    huff[i].w[0] = c;
                    huff[i].v++;
                    counter++;
                    break;
                }
                if (huff[i].w[0]== c){
                    huff[i].v++;
                    break;
                }
                if (i == length - 1){
                    node_t *temp = realloc(huff, (length + expand_size) * sizeof *temp);
                    if(!temp) {
                        printf("relloc failed\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    huff=temp;
                    for (int j = length; j < length + expand_size; j++)
                        huff[j].v = 0;
                    length += expand_size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int n = huffman(&huff, counter);
    for(int i=0; i<counter; i++){
        int l=i;
        if(compression_level == 1)
            printf("%c: ", huff[i].w[0]);
        if(compression_level == 2)
            printf("%c%c: ", huff[i].w[0], huff[i].w[1]);
        while (l!=n-1){
            printf("%c", huff[l].b);
            l = huff[l].d;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    if (steps == 1) {
        for (int i=0; i<counter; i++){
            if( huff[i].w[0] == 10)
                printf("'%d' 'LINE FEED' occured %d razy\n", huff[i].w[0], huff[i].v);
        }
        printf("array length %d\n", length);
        printf("how many nodes %d\n", n);
        printf("how many primary nodes %d\n", counter);
    }
    free(huff);
    fclose(read);
    return 0;
}
```

I also reduced scope of variables, checked return value of `realloc()`, checked that `file` is set.  Here is the valgrind summary after the change:

```
==2612036== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2612036==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2612036==   total heap usage: 41 allocs, 41 frees, 53,016 bytes allocated
==2612036== 
==2612036== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! Could you please explain why we pass the pointer to the function becouse i don't get this part "This means caller retains pointer and the"

Comment: When you pass a variable to a function in C, let's call it `main_huff`, it's copied to a a new variable on let's call it `func_huff`.  They now contain the same value, but they are stored in two different variables.  When we `realloc()` we want to change `main_buff` but we need it's address to do that, and we don't have it.  It probably won't click till you try this: modify your original program and in main print the address of huff and it's address i.e. `printf("%p %p\n", (void *) huff, (void *) &huff)` and do the same thing first thing in the `huffman()` function.

Comment: Okay i kinda get it now, thanks again! Have a great evening.

Comment: @MichałJagodzinski It's an important lesson to really get.  The simplified version is if you want to modify a variable in a function you need to pass in the address of said variable.  It's easier to see for simple variables: `void f(int i)` vs `void f(int *i)`.

Comment: I will remember this for the rest of my life, i lost 2 hours of my life trying to fix it on my own ...